# can we execute shell script using gsutil command

Tags: shell, gsutil, google-cloud-shell

Option to execute shell script using gsutil is nowhere mentioned in the document. Tried some options but still no luck.I have a .sh file ,stored in a storage bucket,is there any way to execute this script using `gsutil` ?

Answer (score 3):

`gsutil` doesn't support direct execution shell scripts, but you could pipe it to a shell, for example:

`gsutil cat gs://your-bucket/your-script.sh | sh`

Comment: Thanks for your answer the above command is perfectly working in cloud shell, but i am trying to execute the script into my dataflow job , i am able to execute gsutil in my job using direct runner so throught of executing shell in gsutil only.Is there any way to connect to cloud shell enviroment in our java dataflow code(i am using windows system so dont think i can run shell using my current enviroment ). Please share if you have any info about this.

Comment: I think it might be more useful to post this as a new question specifically about your scenario, i.e., "How can I achieve X within a Cloud Dataflow job?"  I'm not sure to what extent arbitrary script execution is supported on Dataflow.